# iOS app glitches every time the label value changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I am making a game on Xcode and I am having a problem with the scoring mechanism. My game involves a submarine dodging incoming obstacles. I am not using the Open GL Es. My problem arises with the score. I have a timer that runs a scoring method every 1 second (code below)

```
 Scorer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(Scoring) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Here is the Scoring method.

```
- (void) Scoring
{
    ScoreNumber = ScoreNumber + 1;
    Score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %i", ScoreNumber];
}
```

Every time the score goes up one, the game kind of starts back up at the origin points for the submarine. It is like the view is reloading each time the value of the label goes up. If I forward slash // the `Score.text` part, the game runs fine.

Thanks and I appreciate any help possible. If more information is needed, just say so.

Comment: At which location you have placed scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval method ? and have you stopped timer ?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a consequence of auto layout. If any views are moved or resized by setting frames instead of adjusting the constraints, the views will reset to the frames determined by their constraints whenever the view has to redraw (like when you update your label). To fix this, you either need to turn off auto layout, or do all your moving by modifying constraints.